# Does using Devil Fruit powers drain the user's stamina?

Tags: one-piece

In many cases we see that devil fruit users go easy on their powers.

For example, why didn't Whitebeard spam his Gura Gura powers during the war? 
couldn't he just have destroyed the entire island? or simply from a distance cause massive sea waves on the island before even starting the war?

There was a scene when the three admirals had to block his attack, why didn't he try it again, and again?

Luffy doesn't seem to get tired of using his Gomu Gomu powers, he basically gets tired of punching, running, or fighting..etc

So what's the deal with how Devil Fruit users use their powers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on which Devil Fruit. Some fruits drain their user's stamina when its powers are being used, while some don't.

Example: Luffy's Devil Fruit permantly turns his body into rubber. The fruit's power is active at all times, but Luffy doesn't need to use any stamina to remain in his rubbery state. Luffy's stamina doesn't drain simply by existing.

On the flipside, Law's fruit, the Ope Ope no Mi, does drain his stamina when he uses it. He confirms this himself.

So the conclusion is, it depends on the fruit.

Answer (score 3):

For Whitebeard case he just doesnt want to destroy entire place. If he wanted he can even destroy the planet. You also have to factor his sickness. That's what probably stops him doing that.

Answer (score 3):

it depends on the fruit like for example law's fruit ope ope no mi do drains stamina